# How to merge Git and GitLab users

Tags: ubuntu, git, gitlab, vcs

I am running a new GitLab 8.3 installation and I have imported my old/existing Git repositories. For commits that were created before switching to GitLab, it displays a link to that person's email address but not a link to their profile. Is there a way to associate the old commits with the new GitLab profiles?

Answer (score 0):

Commit to user mapping is done via the email address on the commit. A user can set additional emails in `/profile/emails` - once they add the emails to their gitlab profile, the old commits will be associated to the correct users.

(I'm unfortunately not finding a place in the UI for an admin to add emails to a user other than themselves, might need to directly edit the database if you need to do this for the users instead of having them add the emails on their old commits.)

Comment: Strange, the emails for each user have not changed but I noticed that there are areas in the UI where the link appears correctly and others where it is not.

Comment: Hmm - verify directly in git whether the author data is different at all between those two cases?

Comment: No difference after comparing the author field using `git show xxxxxxxx` of two commits: one with the correct link and one without

Comment: Gitlab sometimes has problems attributing commits when the emails differ in case.